# WordPress Database error when I try to increase posts per page in backend

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress database error:

```
[Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'] INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta`
  (`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 'edit_post_per_page','100')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've modified the `wp_usermeta` table to no longer be set to auto_increment.  Make sure the `umeta_id` field is set to auto_increment and the table's cardinality is set to a number that's greater than the largest existing key.